# Why there is only a `to_string()` for number types?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, tostring

I just got to know that C++ has a [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) defined in `<string>`. Now I wonder why `to_string()` only works with number types. Is there any particular reason, why there isnt a more general

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T& t);
```

?

Could be implemented like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T& t) {
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << t;
    return s.str();
}
```

I suspect that such general `to_string` does not exist, because it is easy to write your own, but the same argument would apply to the `to_string()` taking `int`,`double`, etc.

Comment: Just my two cents... But these functions are way too limited to be worthy of being in std... Something like Boost.Format or lexical_cast would have been a lot, and I mean a lot more useful. These to_string functions are very basic and only useful in the most basic of scenarios, which means they are useless in real life.

Comment: Don't get thrown off by one vote. Might be just a someone having a bad day.

Comment: Actually, there is a proposal about this issue http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0117r0.html, but don't think it would be accepted sometime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the `std::to_string()` requirements.

As the standard states:

> `string to_string(int val);`
>
> `string to_string(unsigned val);`
>
> `string to_string(long val);`
>
> `string to_string(unsigned long val);`
>
> `string to_string(long long val);`
>
> `string to_string(unsigned long long val);`
>
> `string to_string(float val);`
>
> `string to_string(double val);`
>
> `string to_string(long double val);`
>
> Returns: Each function returns **a string object holding the character
>   representation of the value of its argument that would be generated by
>   calling sprintf(buf, fmt, val) with a format specifier of "%d", "%u",
>   "%ld", "%lu", "%lld", "%llu", "%f", "%f", or "%Lf", respectively**,
>   where buf designates an internal character buffer of sufficient size.

Writing a templated function that can determine the specifier that needs to be used for `std::sprintf` makes things unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add to [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401050/4117728) what I found in [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0117r0.html) (thanks to @DAle for the link).

The proposal is about adding a generic `to_string` method. The principle would be the same as with my naive implementation: under the hood a stream is used to get a string from any object that can be streamed.

As the proposal came after c++11, adding such a method would have impact on the existing `to_string` and in the section "Impact on the standard" they write:

> [...] The old and new functions could coexist, relying on the overload
> resolution to prefer a non-templated (existing) version in case of a
> matching argument type. However, a compatibility problem may arise in
> case of some distinct but implicitly convertible argument types:
>
> ```
> to_string(0);     // before: calls to_string(int), now: calls to_string(int)
> to_string(false); // before: calls to_string(int), now: calls to_string<bool>(bool&&)
> to_string('0');   // before: calls to_string(int), now: calls to_string<char>(char&&)
> ```
>
> While the effect is identical in the first two cases (the result is
> always "0"), in the last one the result will change from "48"
> (assuming ASCII encoding) to "0". There are several ways to deal with
> problematic specialisation cases like this one:

And then they list some options (including ignoring the problem) out of which  none would be really satisfying.